# using svnadmin as www-data user

Tags: svn

Howdie

Scenario:

Allow developers to submit new application packages to a market server. Developers run a bash script which contains a cURL call to market server (localhost/market/submit/$app-name). The submit script on the server creates a new folder in existing svn server with the name of the submitted app. Script on dev side waits for HTTP to issue a success message and then do a svn checkout in dev local machine.

Problem:

The submit script on the market server failed to create new svn directory through code:

```
echo `svnadmin mkdir -m 'added new package $package' http://localhost/market/packages/$package`;
```

this does not echo nothing and when I go on http://localhost/market/packages, the folder has not been added and the revision number has not been incremented.

I've tried from a terminal in market server

```
chown root:www-data /usr/bin/svnadmin
```

or

```
chmod 777 /usr/bin/svnadmin
```

but still no luck. Somebody has come acrosss similar problem? Any solutions? Thanks!

Profile:
Linux/Ubuntu, apache subversion

Comment: ok, I've made an error, it should be `svn mkdir`and not `svnadmin mkdir`. working from terminal but still not working from apache ...

Answer (score 1):

ok, noob mistake I did not set right the permissions of the folder that contains the svn server.

```
chown -R www-data:subversion /var/www/market/packages
chmod -R 750 /var/www/market/packages
```

now it works!